# why does a route without path params needs to come before a path with path params

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I ran my code like this I was having errors like `castError: cast to object failed for value new`

```
app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});

app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});
```

**but when I switched the format like this the code was running normally on my local machine.**

```
app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});

app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});
```

What could be the problem is it as a result of my path params or does order count I don't understand as am just beginning to learn express.js

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});

app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});
```

In the format above, the route above the `new` route includes a route parameter `:id`. Express matches anything that comes after `/products` as if it is the route parameter `:id` that's why in the format above you got an error.

For this one, express knows that if what comes after `/products/` is `new`, it will run the code inside the `app.get('/products/new',` callback:

```
  app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});

app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});
```

Comment: so the best way to handle this is to always put my the route containing a path param last

Comment: Exactly. Put the route containing a paramter with the prefix "/products" last, compared to all of the other "/products" routes.

Answer (score 0):

The routes are evaluated in the order that they are defined, and it also doesn't what what an `id` might look like.

So let's say you have a request going to `/products/new`

When your code looks like this:

```js
app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});

app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});
```

The first route declared is `"/products/:id"`, which is a match and `req.params.id` will equal `"new"`. Because there was a match, it will not even look at routes that were declared after it.

*edit how you could have the `"/products/:id"` come first and still work the way you want, probably not the best but an example of the use case for the `next` param

```js
app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    
    if (id === 'new') {
      next();
      return; // important to remember, without it the code below will also fire
    }
    

    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});

app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});
```

Comment: and is they away to make it know what an id might look like and on the general does it mean that routes with path params should always come last

Comment: @theProf. I added an example in my answer of how to use the `next` param, for the example I just checked if it was the work new, but you could similarly check of it's a number or matches some regex or whatever

Answer (score 0):

In this case order matters. If you put the route with the param first (`/products/:id`), it will  treat any routes that start with `/products/` as a param route. Therefore, the route below will be treated as a products api call with id equal to `new`.

```
app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});
```

You can fix this by putting your param route after the new route.

```
app.get('/products/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render("products/new");
});

app.get("/products/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const product = await Product.findById(id);
    res.render('products/show', { product });
});
```